# Mulligan strategy for a burst Shaman

Tags: hearthstone

I'm currently playing the following deck, a Shaman variant with two Doomhammer and two Lavabursts that can deal very high amounts of burst damage:

[image]

<sup>click on the image to see the full size version</sup>

While it worked pretty nicely so far, I still have trouble deciding which cards to mulligan. The deck has almost no early-game minions, the usual rules for minion-focused decks don't really apply here.

What are the general strategies I should follow for the mulligan phase with this deck? The big general question is whether I should keep a Doomhammer if I have it in my starting hand or not.

How should I adapt my mulligan strategy against different classes?

Answer (score 1):

### Hunter / Warlock / Paladin

I'd mulligan [Earth Shock](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Earth_Shock) and [Lava Burst](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Lava_Burst) and [Doomhammer](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Doomhammer).

I'd keep [Flametongue Totem](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Flametongue_Totem) because you can use your Hero Power + [Flametongue Totem](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Flametongue_Totem) to survive the early game if need be.

[Doomhammer](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Doomhammer) is important early only to take out 2 low health minions, but you take all that damage to the face anyway.

Best starting hand would be [Lightning Bolt](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Lightning_Bolt), [Flametongue Totem](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Flametongue_Totem), [Haunted Creeper](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Haunted_Creeper), [Loot Hoarder](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Loot_Hoarder).

I personally really like [Flametongue Totem](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Flametongue_Totem) and I have them in all my Shaman decks that I make. They really make use of your hero power and can be a never ending 2 power creature every turn if not dealt with.

### Mage / Priest / Druid

You are going to want to burst them down and you'll need card draw to get all the cards you need quickly.

I'd mulligan to get [Loot Hoarder](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Loot_Hoarder) and [Earth Shock](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Earth_Shock) early.

Mage, Priest and Druid can all have really annoying minions without an [Earth Shock](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Earth_Shock). Mages use [Mana Wyrms](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Mana_Wyrm) a 1/3 that grows in power, Priests use [Northshire Clerics](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Northshire_Cleric) enabling card draw from a 1/3 minion and most Druids will cast [Mark of the Wild](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Mark_of_the_Wild) a +2/+2 buff early in the game.

The early [Loot Hoarder](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Loot_Hoarder) will stall your opponent on turn 2 and get you a card, hopefully allowing you to play an [Unbound Elemental](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Unbound_Elemental) on turn three, which is the best case in all match ups.

Comment: Hmm, Earth Shock is one card I usually keep against Warlock, it is incredibly good against the Twilight Drakes from a Handlock. Flametongue totem works well if I can get early board control, but it is not something I can play on an empty board.

Comment: Ive always liked earth shock in my opener. Yeah it may be a dead card for a couple of turns, but being a burst shaman you may need to survive and thats it. This card may allow you to do so.